# error in mysql syntax in magento

Tags: mysql, database, magento, syntax-error

Hi I am trying the folowing script to fetch data from magento database but i am grttinf the folowing error

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': Description --104: Meta Description --506: Anahi's Tip --1067: Size & Fit ' at line 15**

```
$conn1 = mysql_pconnect("db.aviesta.com","gys",'d3v3l0p3r$') or die ("Error In Connetion Databse" . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("customer_transaction_dev",$conn1);
//db Connection end
$select=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT A.entity_id AS productID,
A.sku, A.created_at, B.value AS Price,
C.value AS Description,
E.qty AS Quantity,
F.stock_status,
H.Value AS imageURL
FROM catalog_product_entity A
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal B
ON A.entity_id=B.entity_id AND B.store_id=5
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar C
ON A.entity_id=C.entity_id AND C.attribute_id=105 --Description
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_text D
ON A.entity_id=D.entity_id
AND D.attribute_id= 97
--97: Description
--104: Meta Description
--506: Anahi's Tip
--1067: Size & Fit
--1068: Style Ideas
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item E
ON A.entity_id=E.product_id
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item F
ON A.entity_id=F.product_id AND F.website_id=2
INNER JOIN catalog_product_relation G
ON A.entity_id=G.parent_id
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar H
ON A.entity_id=H.entity_id
AND H.attribute_id =106 --Image
WHERE A.attribute_set_id IN (70,71)
AND A.entity_id=26179' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

please tell me where i am doing mistake

Answer (score 3):

Double-dash comments require a following space.

WRONG:

```
--97: Description
```

RIGHT:

```
-- 97: Description
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comments.html

---

Re your comment:

```
WHERE A.attribute_set_id IN (70,71)
AND A.entity_id=26179'
```

You have a stray single-quote at the end of your WHERE clause on line 30 of the query.  The SQL parser counts lines from the start of the SQL statement, not from the start of your file.

---

The only place where `Image` occurs is here:

```
ON A.entity_id=H.entity_id
AND H.attribute_id =106 --Image
```

This is another case where you need a space after the double-dash comment.

There also appears to be one more such case earlier in the query:

```
ON A.entity_id=C.entity_id AND C.attribute_id=105 --Description
```

I tested the query against some empty tables, and once I corrected all the comments by adding spaces, the query worked.

Comment: now it throws this error   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 30   where line thirty is ON A.entity_id=E.product_id in my file

Comment: i think the solutions so far you provided is great but now i got Unknown column 'Image' in 'on clause' error